# Continuing to use pry as a debugger after an exception occurs?

Tags: ruby, pry

Launch PRY:

```
pry problem_12b.rb
```

Here's my console:

```
     5: def divisors
     6:   return [1] if self == 1
     7:   primes, powers = self.prime_division.transpose 
     8:   exponents = powers.map{|i| (0..i).to_a} 
     9:   divisors = exponents.shift.product(*exponents).map do |powers| 
    10:     primes.zip(powers).map{|prime, power| prime ** power}.inject(:*) 
    11:   end 
    12:   divisors.sort.map{|div| [div, self / div]} 
 => 13:   binding.pry
    14: end
```

Let's play in this:

```
28.divisors
p divisors
#[1, 7, 2, 14, 4, 28]
```

Cool... Now say I want to **execute line 12.** I can do this:

```
p divisors.sort.map{|div| [div, self / div]} 
#[[1, 28], [2, 14], [4, 7], [7, 4], [14, 2], [28, 1]]
```

What I would like to do is say: `p line(12)` (You insert code here) because that isn't correct and it blows up.

```
Exception: NoMethodError: undefined method `line' for 28:Fixnum
```

After it blows up how can I **step back** to the first code block above. My only option can't be to `exit!` and `pry problem_12b.rb` again?

***Recap:***

1. How to execute code by pry line number?
2. If I mistype something or it blows up (Exception) how can I revert to previous state?

Comment: AFAIK you cannot do this in pry. check out [elms time travelling debugger](http://debug.elm-lang.org/) for why this is difficult. You can check out [pry-debugger](https://github.com/nixme/pry-debugger) for solving this problem (put the breakpoint earlier and then use step to move forward etc.

Comment: You could write a high-level (or even global) exception handler.  You'll want some kind of "debug flag" so that this handler is only active when debugging.  You'd never want such a handler in production.

Comment: May I suggest a more specific title to your question?  Something like: "*Continuing to use* pry as a debugger *after an exception occurs*?"

Comment: @JaredBeck lets see if it helps! :)